# Set ZoomFactor when page loads

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-rt

How can I set the ZoomFactor of my image using the OnNavigatedTo method? I've tried using this code but it doesn't work.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        imageHolder.ZoomFactor(0.1);
    }
```

hence I get this error:

```
Non-invocable member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer.ZoomFactor' cannot be used like a method.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ZoomToFactor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.zoomtofactor) method. `ZoomFactor` is a read-only property, hence you received the error.